# Проблема с телеграм ботом на питоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Писал игрового бота, первая клавиатура работает нормально, а во второй клавиатуре не работают кнопки, т.е я нажимаю на кнопку и ничего не происходит. Кто знает, как пофиксить? Вот код:

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types 

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    e1 = types.KeyboardButton("Breaking The Bank")
    e2 = types.KeyboardButton("Escaping The Prison")
    e3 = types.KeyboardButton("Stealing The Diamond")
    e4 = types.KeyboardButton("Infiltrating The Airship")
    e5 = types.KeyboardButton("Felling The Complex")
    e6 = types.KeyboardButton("Completing The Mission")
    markup.add(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберете эпизод", reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])    
def U(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == "Breaking The Bank":
            markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            sh = types.KeyboardButton("Shovel")
            ex = types.KeyboardButton("Explosives")
            tp1 = types.KeyboardButton("Teleporter")
            la = types.KeyboardButton("Laser")
            wb = types.KeyboardButton("Wrecking Ball")
            di = types.KeyboardButton("Disguise")
            markup1.add(sh, ex, tp1, la, wb, di)
            introbtb = open("/home/nitrorx/bot/introbtb.mp4", 'rb')
        
            if message.text == "a":
                introbtb = open("/home/nitrorx/bot/shovel.mp4", 'rb')
                bot.send_video(message.chat.id, introbtb, reply_markup=markup1)
            
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри пример простого бота https://github.com/vladrunk/MagicNumberBot
Создание клавиатуры лучше выноси в отдельные функции.

По поводу этого:

```py
def U(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == "Breaking The Bank":
            markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            sh = types.KeyboardButton("Shovel")
            ex = types.KeyboardButton("Explosives")
            tp1 = types.KeyboardButton("Teleporter")
            la = types.KeyboardButton("Laser")
            wb = types.KeyboardButton("Wrecking Ball")
            di = types.KeyboardButton("Disguise")
            markup1.add(sh, ex, tp1, la, wb, di)
            introbtb = open("/home/nitrorx/bot/introbtb.mp4", 'rb')
        
            if message.text == "a":
                introbtb = open("/home/nitrorx/bot/shovel.mp4", 'rb')
                bot.send_video(message.chat.id, introbtb, reply_markup=markup1)
```

Скорее всего доходит до `if message.text=="a"` и стопариться, так как отправка сообщения в этом ифе.
Вынеси `bot.send_message` из ифа.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало